# Output a String that has the categorical value of the final sum seperated out?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

Say I have a field [Client] which is either Yes/No

Then I Sum on [NumberOfAccounts]

But on my map I want a string that says "Clients: 23 Prospects: 11 Total: 33"

How do I do that with a calculated field??

Comment: Show a small bit of relevant sample data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one record, i.e. row of data per account, and an account is either a client or prospect depending on the value of the [Client] field. Further recommend you change Client to a Boolean valued field, taking on either True or False, instead of using a string, and finally assuming you rename the field [Client?]

Give all that, you define a calculated field called [**Clients**] as

```
INT([Client?])
```

And then you can put SUM([Clients]) on the Text/Label shelf to get the number of clients.

Likewise, you can define a calculated field called [**Prospects**] as

```
INT(NOT [Client?])
```

And also put SUM([Prospects]) on the Text/Label shelf.

This works because the type conversion function INT() converts True to 1 and False to 0. Then the SUM() function effectively counts the number of records that satisfy the Boolean condition.

Finally, also add SUM([Number of Records]) to Text/Label.

Once the measures are included in text or label, you can edit the label text by clicking on the Text/Label button on the marks card to add the surrounding strings.

BTW, The button is called either Text or Label depending on your choice of mark type.